# Corrupted file uploaded to S3, Lambda function written for uploading remote file to S3 in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to fetch media file (mp4 & jpeg) from remote url and uploading it to S3. File gets uploaded at desired location in s3 but when download or open the file, It is corrupted.

It looks like problem is in downloading the file or it doesn't have compatible base64 format for S3.

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({ params: {Bucket: 'my-bucket-name'} });  
var request = require("request")
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            url:"<my media url>",
            json:true,
            gzip: true
        }, function(error,res, body){
            if (!error && res.statusCode === 200) {
                for(var i=0; i < body.snapList[i].length; i++) {
                    var snapId = body.snapList[i].snapId;
                    var snapUrl = body.snapList[i].snapUrls.mediaUrl;
                    console.log("Ths value of array is " + i);
                    UploadFromUrlToS3(
                    snapUrl,
                    'videos/' + snapId )
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log('image was saved...');
                    }).catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('image was not saved!',err);
                    });
                }
            }
        })
    });
};

/** upload media in s3 **/
function UploadFromUrlToS3(url,destPath){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {            
        request({
            url: url,
            encoding: null,
            gzip: true
        }, function(err, res, body) {        
            if (err){
                reject(err);
            }
            console.log("Content type of media is " + res.headers['content-type']);
            if(res.headers['content-type'] == 'video/mp4') {
                destPath = destPath + '.mp4';
            } else {
                destPath = destPath + '.jpeg';
            }
            var objectParams = {
                ContentType: res.headers['content-type'],
                ContentLength: res.headers['content-length'],
                Key: destPath,
                Body: body,
                ACL: 'public-read',
            };
            resolve(s3.putObject(objectParams).promise());
        });
    });
}
```

I am expecting file to be uploaded non-corrupted in S3.

Comment: The examples uploading .jpg files [in the AWS JavaScript SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) don't use base64 encoding with `s3.putObject `. Have you confirmed that the files are actually downloading correctly by saving them somewhere on your local disk first?

Comment: "Have you confirmed that the files are actually downloading correctly by saving them somewhere on your local disk first?" This is what I needed, code is perfectly fine. The source videos itself corrupted. Thank you for pointing out. @AlwaysLearning

Comment: Glad to be of help!